# How to apply a function to the entire table in a dplyr chain

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dplyr chain as follows

```
myResults <- rawData %>% filter(stuff) %>% mutate(stuff)
```

now I want to apply a function `myFunc` to `myResults`. Is there a way to do that in the chain or do I need to basically do:

```
myResults <- myFunc(myResult)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If function takes a dataframe as a first argument, you can simple add it at the end.

```
> myFunc <- function(x) sapply(x, max)
> mtcars  %>% filter(mpg > 20) %>%  myFunc()
    mpg     cyl    disp      hp    drat      wt    qsec      vs      am    gear 
 33.900   6.000 258.000 113.000   4.930   3.215  22.900   1.000   1.000   5.000 
   carb 
  4.000
```

It is worth mention that `magrittr::%>%` which is used by `dplyr` works with any argument so you can easily do something like this:

```
> inc <- function(x) x + 1
> 1 %>% inc(.) %>% sqrt(.) %>% log(.)
[1] 0.3465736
```

and with some useful `magrittr` aliases:

```
library(magrittr)
set.seed(1)
inTrain <- sample(1:nrow(mtcars), 20)
mtcarsTest <- mtcars %>% extract(-inTrain, )

summaryPipe <- function(x) {print(summary(x)); x}

mtcars %>%
    extract(inTrain, ) %>% 
    # Train lm
    lm(mpg ~ ., .) %>%
    # Print summary and forward lm results
    summaryPipe %>%
    # Predict on the test set
    predict(newdata = mtcarsTest) %>%
    # Print results and forward arguments
    print %>%
    # Compute RMSE
    subtract(mtcarsTest %>% extract2('mpg')) %>%
    raise_to_power(2) %>%
    mean %>%
    sqrt
```

It is probably a matter of taste but personally I find it rather useful.

As @BondedDust mentioned in the comments there are three possible ways of passing a function to `%>%`. With dot placeholder you can use LHS on a different position than the first (see `lm` call).

Comment: I don't know how much it matters in this case, but it might be more efficient to use `lapply(x, max)` rather than the `apply` call in the body of that example function. It might look better if you did it with `%>%  myFunc(.)` or just `%>%  myFunc`. To my eyes, seeing an empty argument list  suggests that nothing is being processed, but that's perhaps just an aesthetic quibble

Comment: `apply` output is just easier to copy and paste, but of course you're right.

Comment: OK, then use `sapply` if you want a vector result. Early users of R are forever reaching for `apply` first, and they need to either be warned that it often has undesirable consequences

Answer (score 1):

You can use the existing functions `summarise_each` or `mutate_each` to apply to all columns or `select` a subset of columns

```
   library(dplyr)
   mtcars %>% 
     filter(mpg > 20) %>%
     summarise_each(funs(max))
   #   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
   #1 33.9   6  258 113 4.93 3.215 22.9  1  1    5    4
```

Or passing an external function

```
  myFunc1 <- function(x) max(x)
  mtcars %>% 
     filter(mpg > 20) %>%
     summarise_each(funs(myFunc1))
 #   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
 #1 33.9   6  258 113 4.93 3.215 22.9  1  1    5    4
```